# Break down integers greater than 10 into its components from an elixir list

Tags: elixir

How do I take a list of say `[1,2,3,45,67,]` and break it down to `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`?

Answer (score 5):

It can be done without string conversion:

```
Enum.flat_map([1, 2, 3, 45, 67], &Integer.digits/1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 45, 67] 
|> Enum.map(&Integer.to_string/1) 
|> Enum.flat_map(&String.graphemes/1)
|> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1) # results in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension.

```rb
for << <<c>> <- Enum.join([1, 2, 3, 45, 67]) >>, do: c - ?1 + 1
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```